# How next value is generated for auto increment primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi I'm working on a project database using Java and SQL(XAMPP).

Why "ID" does not increment to the next available value. Take note that I deleted all of the consecutive numbers from 2-8. and the "ID" have A_I(Auto Increment).

```
ID     username password fname mname lname course address contact status

1     31231231    123     new   old  smith  BSCS   123      123    USER

9      123       ASD     ASD    ASD ASD    BSCpE  ASD       123    USER
```

Why it is (1,9) not (1,2)?

Comment: `"I deleted some of the consecutive numbers from 2-8"` - It looks like you deleted *all* of the records from 2-8.  If you deleted them, why do you expect them to still show up in your query?

Answer (score 3):

There you answered your question. You deleted numbers between 2-8.

So it is a MySQL database, auto-increment do not increment the number based on maximum value of the column.

Think about it. It would be much less effective to calculate maximum number in a table and increment it for the next record.

Instead writing down the last number used on that column somewhere and increment it when a new one is requested is much more effective.

I am not a MySQL guru, but MySQL obviously uses an internal mechanism as a sequence to increment a column value.

It is perfectly fine to have non-consecutive numbers if you delete one. In fact i think in most cases it is desirable. Leave it as it is. As long as the numbers are unique, why should that bother you ?

Comment: I see, I'm new to sql that's why I'm adventuring myself into it. Thanks for the clarification. It's just that it bothers me to see (1,6,8,9..) than (1,2,3,4..). Does it affect anything? Or unless it will, if I include the column of "ID" right?

Comment: It's not only "less effective" to re-use a number, it's downright dangerous.  Identifiers are meant to, well, identify something.  Two distinct objects shouldn't have the same identifier if they're not exactly the same thing, even if one of them doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @Starvinmarvinnn: In the long run it would end up bothering you *a lot more* if your identifiers weren't unique.

Comment: Thank you guys for enlightening me. Big help! Cheers!

Comment: you would see this also where insert inside transactions which were rolled back or where a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is used (not a fan of using that on tables with auto_increment).

Answer (score 1):

Numbers could be non-consecutive due to (a) deletions, or (b) IDs that were generated inside a transaction that was never committed.

The other answers pointed out some problems with reuse of IDs. The biggest problem is what happens when an ID is reused after it has been shared with another system outside the consistency boundary of the originating database, i.e. replication to another SQL Server database, or via integration middleware to arms-length systems.

Bottom line: don't reuse IDs ever.